# A reference for solution of non homogeneous heat equation on bounded domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, linear-pde, parabolic-pde, dispersive-pde

In PDE's book from Evans, is said that
$$
u(x,t) = \int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{1}{(4\pi (t-s))^{N/2}} e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4(t-s)}} f(y,s) dy ds
$$
is a solution of
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t - \Delta u = f, \mathbb{R}^N \times (0, \infty) \\
u = 0, \mathbb{R}^N \times \{t = 0\}
\end{cases}
.
$$
I would like to know if is it possible to find a explicitly solution for the equation

$$
\begin{cases}
u_t - \Delta u = f, \Omega \times (0, \infty) \\
u(x,0) = 0 , \Omega \\
u = 0, \partial \Omega \times \{t > 0\} \\
\end{cases}
,
$$
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded domain, for example, on a ball. Any refence in this topic is welcome.

Comment: The short answer is no - only in the absolute simplest cases for $\Omega $ and $f$ is this possible